# C# MVC - Strange compilation error code -2146232576

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I published a web app with C# MVC on IIS, but when I try to access the site, the server show this error; But I published the same web app in other Server and this run without issues. (I updated the NugetPackage)

> Server Error in '/Outlet' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
> required to service this request. Please review the following specific
> error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code
> -2146232576.
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36392

I'm searching for this error code but don't find any solution, someone knows the possible solution for this error code?

Comment: What version of the framework are you building it for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Compilation Error -2146232576 AspNetInitializationExceptionModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892851/iis-compilation-error-2146232576-aspnetinitializationexceptionmodule)

Comment: @JuanRomero I used .Net 4.6

Comment: @Rahul I tryed with those solution but don't work :/

Comment: Are you sure the server has the right version installed?

Comment: Yes, beacuse I have other pages in this server with the same framework and run without issues

Comment: What about the application pool it's using though. It may be assigned to a different one. Did you check that?

Comment: @JuanRomero yes, I used Application Pool ASP.NET v4.0 and in the web.config file used targetFramework="4.0"

Comment: OK. Did you try removing the `<compiler>` section from your web.config?

Comment: I removed this label before publish it, I just change pool app and now says >"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Comment: The path is Server/Outlet/Index , in the local runs okey but in the server side don't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159496/discussion-between-juan-romero-and-javier-insuasti).