# Compilation Error Mvc on iis6 win server 2003

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I try to run an ASP.NET MVC aplication on iis6 on win server 2003. 
The application work fine on my local iis which on win7. But it gives compilation error with 2146232576 error code.

Is there a missing dll or something on the server.

Version İnfo: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36400

Comment: So, if you deploy the application from visual studio to the server, it gives you that error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892851/iis-compilation-error-2146232576-aspnetinitializationexceptionmodule

Comment: I publish the application, then i copy and paste the files to the location on the server.

Comment: Did you try the third solution(the one that has 15 upvotes)...try doing that, compile the solution and then copy the files to the server

Comment: Yes, i tried it.I think it worked.

Comment: Nice, give that user another upvote :)